# Pause Timer in Android app

Tags: android, multithreading

In a release method and insert data into a database in another database update in execution SQLite throws exception, I need to pause and resume thread. My plan is to run a single method to query my database so not to cause errors.

My timer,

```
cron = new Timer();
    cron.schedule(scanTask = new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CronPush.class));
         }
    }, 0, 30000);



@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        cron.cancel();
        Sincronizacion s = new Sincronizacion();
        s.sincronizarBD(MenuEvento.this, codigoEvento);
        resume();
        return null;
    }


public void resume() {
    cron = new Timer();
    cron.schedule(scanTask = new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CronPush.class));
         }
    }, 0, 30000);
}


03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
```

03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:572)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:481)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at com.androidaz.scanner.MenuEvento.resume(MenuEvento.java:266)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at com.androidaz.scanner.MenuEvento$sincronizarBD.doInBackground(MenuEvento.java:216)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at com.androidaz.scanner.MenuEvento$sincronizarBD.doInBackground(MenuEvento.java:1)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-27 23:19:49.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4603):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Timer.cancel()` to drop it if exception is throwed, after create new `Timer` object to schedule again. Using `Timer`, you cannot pause/resume it, just cancel forever.

```
TimerTask cronTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CronPush.class));
     }
};

Timer cron = new Timer();
cron.schedule(cronTimerTask, 0, 30000);

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    if (cron != null) {
        cron.cancel();
        cron.purge();
    }
    Sincronizacion s = new Sincronizacion();
    s.sincronizarBD(MenuEvento.this, codigoEvento);
    resume();
    return null;
}


public void resume() {
    try {
        cron = new Timer();
        cron.schedule(cronTimerTask, 0, 30000);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        cron = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit the POST and show you the error that I get to do what you say, to see if you can help me.

Comment: does not run startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CronPush.class));

Comment: what is purpose of scheduling timer and cancelling it? You schedule timer to start new service every 30 second, is it really what you want?

Comment: I need to do an action every 5 minutes (30 is to go test) discharge data from a WS and the action you want to apply every 5 minutes is a pull, my BD, then the insert and update are done at the same time gives me error

Comment: so if the error is occured when you do your DB job, it is not about timer... You should discover what's wrong with your `sincronizarBD()` method